# Fixing sub-optimal Tempstar furnace vent installation but can't find part numbers

Tags: hvac, repair, furnace, exhaust-vent

I have a Tempstar N9MSE0601714A furnace with 2" PCV vent pipes (that mate to 2.5" pipes).  Whoever installed it didn't fallow the installation manual and I'm also reducing the number of angles in the ducts so need to replace anyway.

Installation is supposed to have Furnace Duct Connector installed on both inlet and outlet and a strain relief adapter on the outlet.  But this is how it's installed:

[image]

I've verified the locations of the in and out are fine but the connections to the cover are functional but sketchy.

From [this doc, page 38, fig 41 and 43](https://www.questargas.com/ForEmployees/qgcOperationsTraining/Furnaces/Day&Night_N9MSE_N9MSB_A_SERIES.pdf):

[image]

I've found the plastic [bracket](https://www.repairclinic.com/PartDetail/Duct-Connector/1012284/2762063) and [gasket](https://www.repairclinic.com/PartDetail/Gasket/1012583/2762135) and a parts list [here](http://www.graycoolingman.com/uploads/1/0/6/6/10667336/9mpd_n9mpd_n9mp1_n9mp2_series_technical_manual_-_parts_list.pdf) but can't find the part number for the rubber adapter circled above.  I'm assuming the one I do have is damaged since they jammed it into the hole in the cover instead of sitting atop the adapter plate.

What is the OEM part number for the rubber bushing/connector/adapter circled above?